# Python 2.7: When importing into dataframe, I get IO error 'file does not exist', even when I provide absolute path

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, io, anaconda

I'm using Anaconda to run Pandas, and I'm attempting to import a CSV into a dataframe.

> import pandas as pd
>
> df = pd.read_csv(r'C:/users/aliceell/desktop/oregon_2013_var_list')

Even though I have directly copy-pasted the path directly from the file, it still keeps saying "IOError: File C:/users/aliceell/desktop/oregon_2013_var_list does not exist". You can see in this image: [image], from the File Properties, that the path is accurate. I've checked to make sure the file isn't read-only, and that I have the right permissions. I've moved the file around to different folders. I've even tried moving it to the Python directory and using a relative path instead. What am I doing wrong? I feel like there's some small stupid mistake in the code that I'm missing, but I can't figure out what.

I'm running Windows 7 64-bit. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't have the extension on the end of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the file extension from the end of your file path. From the screenshot you provided, it looks like the file extension is `.csv`. Give this a shot:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:/users/aliceell/oregon_2013_var_list.csv')
```

Also, from your screenshot, it looks like you may have the path wrong as well. If the above doesn't work, try this as well:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:/users/aliceell/desktop/oregon_2013_var_list.csv')
```

Comment: That was it. I thought I had tried adding the extension earlier, but I guess not, or if I did, I didn't add it correctly. I knew it was some stupid mistake like that...Thank you!

Comment: @Alice Glad I could help!